# How to locate the fuse of this FAAC automatic gate controller?

Tags: gates

I have tried to locate a manual (as seen in the picture) on FAAC's website. The model number XF 433 turns out to be the code of the radio module.

[image]

At the moment the a swing leaf gate it controls is not responding. I suspect it is caused by a blown fuse due to a recent storm.

Where is the fuse and how can I replace it? Do I need to remove the radio module (XF 433) before I take of the frosty plastic cover?

Comment: why don't you take off the cover and look for a fuse?

Comment: Do you mean the frosted plastic cover? I am not familiar with the unit, so I want some instructions.

Comment: it's not rocket science  ... wiggle the cover ... look for latches or screws at places where the cover appears to bind ... otherwise, call a gate service tech

Comment: Are you just making a general commentary or you indeed know about this hardware?

Comment: general commentary and lots of experience with many various pieces of hardware

Comment: Most of us won't have specific experience with a given piece of hardware -- but it turns out engineers who make hardware tend to follow patterns. We learn to identify those patterns. There are a red+black pair of wires going to the top, near where the frosted cover says POWER. Through the cover we see an array of cylinders with silver tops; both of these things are signs that the board's power supply is in that area. If the board has a fuse on its input that's the area where it'll almost certainly be found. Figure out how to remove the cover and have a look.

Comment: Are you sure the controller unit is an "FAAC XF-43"? Could that just be the make and model of that individual component?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it It turns out 433 is the model number of the radio unit. The control board seems to be a E024S but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @GregHill I agree with your general principle, but I come to this site looking for more specific advices.

Comment: @Anthony Kong- is it powered by house voltage (AC) or by a charger and battery (DC)?

Comment: @ojait House voltage.

Comment: Can you check the power source (outlet) to verify there's power?

Comment: If not the breaker may need to be reset that the controller is powered by.

Comment: Yeah, the power socket is live.

Comment: So the problem does lie in the board. The fuse would look like a small glass cylinder held in place by 2 "u" shaped clips. Theres a thin wire in the center that will probably be burnt. Take a wider photo and I can try to help more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fuse is located under the logic board. (see attached photo)

[image]

It is actually not necessary to remove the frosty plastic cover of the logic board. As a matter of fact, removing the cover incorrectly **could bend and damage** the pins of the radio module.

The fuse is a glass fuse T2A.

Answer (score 1):

@Anthony Kong- There is a fuse. It may be resettable or replaceable. Here's your link for the [maanual](https://faac.blob.core.windows.net/web/1/accessories-and-control-boards/control-boards/for-swing-gates/e024s-control-board/e024s-revd-gb.pdf). Let me know what happens or if I can help.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but link-only answers (which this is basically) are discouraged since links can die. I'd suggest going though the manual and transcribing the fuse information into your answer,

Comment: yeah it takes half a minute to copy a screenshot from a pdf or web page into an answer, less if you can cut and paste text.

Comment: @ojait Actually, I am correct. Here is a direct quote from the help page on writing answers: “ Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.”

Comment: I said "link **only** answers are discouraged" not "link answers are discouraged".

Comment: this is an answer with a link. i answered "there is a fuse..." and shared a link.

Comment: and the comment from the OP stating this answer was helpful gets deleted?